# "Even to" or "To even"?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I am not sure which one is grammatically correct. It could be both or none. Could you select which sentence would be grammatically correct?

The only difference between the sentences is *even to* vs. *to even*:

> 1. Students over the age of 16 who are considering to be employed by business companies should be incredibly concerned; it is extremely difficult ***to even*** get an opportunity for an interview.
> 2. Students over the age of 16 who are considering to be employed by business companies should be incredibly concerned; it is extremely difficult ***even to*** get an opportunity for an interview.

Comment: What rule of English grammar do you purport this to be a violation of? You should look instead to “considering to be employed”, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this must be corrected (thanks, tchrist):

who are considering to be employed --> who are **considering employment**

Now, to your choices: none of the two is the best.

The way to do it:
Go to Google Books (not vanilla Google); select and test your **critical cores**.

**The best (and the most natural)** is at the top here:

[**"difficult  to  get even an"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20is%20extremely%20difficult%20to%20even%20get%20an%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22difficult%20%20to%20%20get%20even%20an%22)
**About 1,990 results**

"difficult even to  get an"
About 246 results

"difficult to even get an"
About 127 results

Grammatical reason: it is considered best for clarity's sake **to place the emphasizer ("even," here) closest to the entity of interest.**

Comment: Neither of the two is *better* (than the other). *Best* applies to three or more.

Comment: When I said "the best" I referred myself to the available choices, which here are at least three:-)

Comment: You really should explain that “considering to be employed” is the actual grammatical error. There is no grammatical error with the placement of *evan* here, only better and worse positioning for the strength of the sentence.

Answer (score -2):

I think  real distinction is just the utterance these two cases represent. In my mind they are distinct utterances

A comma, in the second case, after difficult, if you will.

Comment: This needs some explanation of what you mean by "distinct utterances" in these sentences.

Comment: And some links backing up your explanations would be even better.

Comment: You might also [edit] your post so that it conforms to the basic conventions. An article in the first sentence. Punctuation to complete the second. Answers, unlike comments, are expected to be correct in grammar and orthography: we are site for *serious enthusiasts of English*, after all.